# How to efficiently sync data via android sockets among multiple devices

Tags: android, json, sockets, mobile, synchronization

I am developing a mobile app for restaurants so that waiters can take order on a mobile phone. Currently I need this app to be installed on four mobile phones and I need an order placed on one phone to be synced across all other phones via a LAN network. The communication should be entirely over the LAN as there is no internet in the phones or in the restaurant.

In this 3 of the mobiles will have the same application to take orders and one which acts as a master device have a separate application which has the ability to take orders and make the payments.

I have looked into Android P2P, but that's not useful for me because some of the devices are below android 4.0 so the only solution I came across is socket communication.

So what is the best approach for me to use socket communication in this scenario. I should also mention that I am sending a large JSON file through the sockets which has the order.

Once an order is placed should I send the order from that mobile to All other Mobiles in a loop or should I send the order to the master device first and that device send the order to all other devices in a loop. I have tried both of the above methods, but its not that good. Sometimes orders does not sync with some devices.

below is my code which sends the JSON to all devices in a loop. Is my code correct?

```
    Iterator i = hardwareList.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) { 

       beHardware hardware = (beHardware) i.next();
       prepAndSendSocketMessage(hardware.getIp(), jsonStringToSend);   

    }
```

and this is the  prepAndSendSocketMessage() method

```
    private boolean prepAndSendSocketMessage(String host,String jsonStringToSend)
    {
        int port = 51253;
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {

            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), 5000);
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(jsonStringToSend.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm quite interested in which scenario you ended up using, since I currently find myself on a similar scenario. Could you point me in the right direction with the android P2P solution, as I may not have the >4.0 restriction. Thanks in advance

Comment: I used it as I mentioned on my question above with ine device as the server, distributing everything to everyone.

Comment: And how did you resolve the issue with sometimes orders not synchronizing?